# multiprocessing to run some scripts

Tags: bash, scripting

can you help me to solve the following problem.
i wanna code a sh file in OS kalilinux to run some scripts.
this is my program structure.

```
count_times=$1;
for i in $(seq 1 $count_times)
    do script_1
    wait
done
script_2
```

i want that, every time script_1 finished a file will be created and the script_2 will process the file while the script_1 continues to create file.
i mean how to write code to run the for loop and scrip_2 in parallel.
thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash

count_times=$1;
fre=$2;
for i in $(seq 1 $count_times)
    do 
    grgsm_capture -s 1e6 -g 40 -c file_name$i.cfile -f $fre -T 120
    wait
done
grgsm_decode -s 1e6 -f 943.8M -c file_name1.cfile -m SDCCH8 -t 1
```

Comment: `a file will be created` - what file? How's it's named? The `file_name$i.cfile` will be created? Please post some more exaplanation. What does those `grgsm_capture` do? The first creates the `file_name$i.cfile` file, then the second should parse it, right? `continues to create file` - the same file? So two programs will operate on the same file at the same time? Won't they conflict with each other?

Comment: grgsm_capture will create a file with the name file_name$i.cfile. the first file will be created named file_name1.cfile. after finishing to create the first file the for loop will create the second  file named file_name2.cfile.

Comment: grgsm_decode will decode the captured file. it will not create file. i wan the for loop and grgsm_decode will run in parallel.

Comment: yes. so i need another for loop for grgsm_decode to decode each created file from the first for loop.

Comment: and now, i need two for loop run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

So just run in background using `&`.

```
#!/bin/bash

count_times=$1;
fre=$2;
for i in $(seq 1 "$count_times"); do
    grgsm_capture -s 1e6 -g 40 -c file_name"$i".cfile -f "$fre" -T 120
    # will start grgsm in the background
    grgsm_decode -s 1e6 -f 943.8M -c file_name"$i".cfile -m SDCCH8 -t 1 &
done

# wait for all the background jobs to finish
wait
```